# GitHub: Linux Android Kernel source. Cannot push or pull

Tags: git, github, linux-kernel, git-push

I am trying to push my kernel source to github but I get an error:

```
$ git push origin master
Write failed: Broken pipe13/37078), 10.77 MiB | 65 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Lopicl/ThunderKernel_cooperve.git'
```

Please, what i do?

I tried also forking a repo and trying to push a commit but I get this error:

```
To git@github.com:Lopicl/thunderkernel_cooperve.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Lopicl/thunderkernel_cooperve.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I tried pulling the repo and:

```
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

Now I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit or stash all your files before you can pull.

Below a simple way to add all files, commit them and push them to the `master` branch on the `origin` remote:

```
git add -A                          # Add all files to the index
git commit -m 'Your commit message' # Commit modifications
git pull origin master              # Get last changes (useless if you work on only one computer)
git push origin master              # Send changes
```

Comment: Many thanks now i solved typing: "git add ." and "git add -u", then "git push etcetera etcerera..."